# How do Banners get Caculated for "Today's Events"

Tags: heroes-of-dragon-age

Today's Events are 24-48 hour PVP events within the game that give increasingly better rewards for earning more "banners".  Sometimes I'll find players on level 60+ with a single common hero on their team worth 20 banners.  Other times, I'll see a team full of legendary heroes, and it's only worth 10 banners.    Any idea how it determines how many banners defeating a particular player is worth?

Comment: It definitely factors in the number of banners the other player has. Other than that, I have a sneaking suspicion that it takes into account the "value" of the enemy team (taking into account event-based bonuses).

Comment: @MrUniverse, Do you're on trophies factor into it at all?

Comment: Of course, as you progress you will be matched against opponents with more banners and get the same amount of rewards.